# WinForms reading control from embedded form

Tags: c#, winforms

Fairly new to WinForms. I have a main form (`Main`) that contains a `SplitContainer` (`container`) with two panels (`Panel1` and `Panel2`)

In `container.Panel1`, I have a combobox (`selectFY`), and a button.  Clicking the button loads a second form in `container.Panel2` like:

```
    private void btnButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        container.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.TopLevel = false;
        form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        container.Panel2.Controls.Add(form);
        form.Show();
     }
```

What I am trying to do is from within the code of Form2, read the `selectedText` value from the `selectFY` combobox in `container.Panel1`

I have tried:

- Accessing as `Main.container.Panel1.selectFY.selectedText`
- Creating a link to Main like

  ```
  Main mainform = new Main();
  var fy = mainform.container.Panel1.selectFY.selectedText
  ```

But neither has worked.

Comment: Read example 2 or example 3 in linked post. You can create a public property in the child form and access the control through it. Also you can set the control to be public and access to control directly.

Comment: @Reza - Thanks...that is what I needed.  In the examples I had read, I never saw making the individual element public.  That did the trick with the second method I had tried before.

Comment: Yes, you can make the control public and it will be useful in some cases. But in general creating a public method or property is recommended.

Comment: By the way. if you find the linked post useful, it would be great to vote for the question and the answer. It's not compulsory at all, this way you make them more popular and more useful for future readers :)